shutil.make_archive works but throws Error 13 for /root
I have a script that collects various files into a directory structure than creates a final zip archive. The directory <dir> is located at /home/<user>/<dir> and I want it to create /home/<user>/<dir>.tar.gz
The archive is created successfully with:
shutil.make_archive(base_name="/home/<user>/<dir>", format='gztar', root_dir="/home/<user>/", base_dir="<dir>", owner="1000", group="1000")

But, after creating the archive is throws an exception:
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 561, in make_archive
    os.chdir(save_cwd)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root'

I explicitly called out the base_name, format, etc. in the function call since that helped some people. I also looked at the make_archive and I cannot figure out why it is trying to access /root when I am doing everything inside of /home/<user>
Everything "works" but this exception stands out in the error log.
